# Vuelidate validation of computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

In my Vue component I have 3 numeric fields, like this:

```
data() {
    return {
        numberAdults: 0,
        numberChildren: 0,
        numberInfants: 0,
    }
```

and also a computed property:

```
computed: {
    numberPersons() {
        return this.numberAdults + this.numberChildren + this.numberInfants
    },
```

I want to validate that at least one person is set (at least one adult or one child or one infant), but I cannot make this to work. This is the validation rule:

```
numberPersons: {
    required,
    minValue: minValue(1),
},
```

If I change the `numberPersons` with one of the three fields, the validation for that field works. I think that somehow Vuelidate doesn't know what `numberPersons` is, but I am not sure how to change that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a custom validation method, say, `minNumberPersons` that simply validates your computed property `this.numberPersons`:

```
const minNumberPersons = (value, vm) => {
    return vm.numberPersons >= 1;
};
```

Then, you can apply these rules to the different models:

```
validations: {
  numberAdults: { minNumberPersons },
  numberChildren: { minNumberPersons },
  numberInfants: { minNumberPersons }
}
```

**UX suggestion, totally optional**: On a side note, since you are going to be validating 3 fields at the same time, it makes sense to use the `$v.<field>.$touch()` method to ensure that the dirty state of all 3 fields are set to `true` when any of them are changed. You can simply do a `@input="onInput"` binding in your template, and add this to your methods:

```
onInput() {
  this.$v.numberAdults.$touch();
  this.$v.numberChildren.$touch();
  this.$v.numberInfants.$touch();
},
```

See proof-of-concept here. I have adapted it from the [demo JSFiddle used by the Vuelidate repository](http:////%20Boilerplate%20adapted%20from%20Vuelidate%27s%20default%20demo:%20https://jsfiddle.net/Frizi/b5v4faqf/).

```js
Vue.use(window.vuelidate.default);

const numberPersons = (value, vm) => {
  return vm.numberPersons >= 1;
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    numberAdults: 0,
    numberChildren: 0,
    numberInfants: 0,
  },
  validations: {
    numberAdults: { numberPersons },
    numberChildren: { numberPersons },
    numberInfants: { numberPersons }
  },
  computed: {
    numberPersons() {
      // Converting each to a number using the unary + operator, in case user inputs empty string
      return (+this.numberAdults) + (+this.numberChildren) + (+this.numberInfants);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    status(validation) {
      return {
        error: validation.$error,
        dirty: validation.$dirty
      }
    },

    // Optional: force validation of all number inputs when any one is changed
    onInput() {
      this.$v.numberAdults.$touch();
      this.$v.numberChildren.$touch();
      this.$v.numberInfants.$touch();
    },
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.dirty {
  border-color: #5A5;
  background: #EFE;
}

.dirty:focus {
  outline-color: #8E8;
}

.error {
  border-color: red;
  background: #FDD;
}

.error:focus {
  outline-color: #F99;
}
```

```html
<!-- Boilerplate adapted from Vuelidate's default demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Frizi/b5v4faqf/ -->

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuelidate/dist/vuelidate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model.number="$v.numberAdults.$model" :class="status($v.numberAdults)" @input="onInput" type="number">
  <input v-model.number="$v.numberChildren.$model" :class="status($v.numberChildren)" @input="onInput" type="number">
  <input v-model.number="$v.numberInfants.$model" :class="status($v.numberInfants)" @input="onInput" type="number">
  <br />
  <br />
  Total number of people: <strong>{{ numberPersons }}</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Even though this snippet works, I cannot make it work in my component. Is there any way I can debug / see the value returned by that custom validation method `numberPersons`?

Comment: After further investigation, it looks like `vm.numberPersons` comes undefined.

Comment: @HMihail It might help for you to provide a minimal, concrete and verifiable example: as you can see from the code snippet I've provided, it works as intended.